# JavaScript closure parameters

Tags: javascript

`foo` is equal to `iCantThinkOfAName`, but the `iCantThinkOfAName` has two parameters, and `foo` only one. I don’t understand how `foo(2)` returns `num: 4`.

```js
function iCantThinkOfAName(num, obj) {
  // This array variable, along with the 2 parameters passed in, 
  // are 'captured' by the nested function 'doSomething'
  var array = [1, 2, 3];

  function doSomething(i) {
    num += i;
    array.push(num);
    console.log('num: ' + num);
    console.log('array: ' + array);
    console.log('obj.value: ' + obj.value);
  }
  return doSomething;
}
var referenceObject = {
  value: 10
};
var foo = iCantThinkOfAName(2, referenceObject); // closure #1
var bar = iCantThinkOfAName(6, referenceObject); // closure #2
foo(2);

/*
num: 4
array: 1,2,3,4
obj.value: 10
*/
```

Comment: what is num with foo(3)? 5 -  what is num with  bar(2) - 8 ... does that help?

Comment: by the way, foo(2) doesn't "return" anything

Comment: … and `foo` is _not_ equal to `iCantThinkOfAName`.

Comment: Why don’t you understand it? It’s just how closures work. What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` is *not* equal to `iCantThinkOfAName`, it is equal to `iCantThinkOfAName(2, referenceObject)` which returns the inner function `doSomething` within a closure containing `num` (which is equal to the `2` you passed in), `obj` which is your `referenceObject` you passed in, and `array = [1, 2, 3];`.

When you call `foo(2)` you are directly calling that inner `doSomething` where `i` is your `2` you are passing in, which gets added to your `num` which was your original `2`; thus, `num` within the closure, is now `4`.

Comment: This is actually a really clear and great explanation of what’s going on in the code and what each function does.